# Can `i2c-mux` be applied to `i2c-0`?

Tags: i2c, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I have a Pi with `i2c-0` working fine and seeing addresses. I'd like to use a I2C multiplexer on `i2c-0`.

Using a I2C multiplexer on `i2c-1` is very easy by having this in `/boot/config.txt`...

```
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtoverlay=i2c-mux,pca9548,addr=0x70
```

I guess I'm wishing for something like this to be possible...

```
dtoverlay=i2c-0-mux,pca9548,addr=0x70
# or
dtoverlay=i2c-mux,pca9548,addr=0x70,bus=0
```

...the idea being find a way to identify the `0` bus rather than the normal `1` bus.

But looking at the docs and the installed `dtoverlay`s, this doesn't seem possible?

Is it possible?

Comment: Why?  Is something not working?  What?  Why is using one line rather than three important to you.  What do you mean by `is2-mux`?

Comment: `is2-mux` was a typo in the title; I meant `i2c-mux`.

Using one line isn't the goal. I'm trying to _change_ the third line to enable multiplexing on `i2c-0` (rather than the normal `i2c-1`).

Comment: You need to add clarifications to your question.  We should not need to read comments to understand the question.  As an aside I would just attach the multiplexer to the bus and use it manually.  I see no advantage in going through a kernel interface to control the device.

Comment: I'm sorry, I _thought_ the first sentence does express what I want: To run a I2C mutiplexer on `i2c-0`. On the Pi it's very easy to run a I2C mutiplexer on `i2c-1` using `dtoverlay=i2c-mux,pca9548,addr=0x70`. But I'm hoping for a way to run it as easily on `i2c-0`. I will clarify that.